# How to use an array or some other device in Visual Basic to populate a table with strings and integers?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm working on a project that involves having a collection of characters that all have different attributes that I want to put into a table. I've made a class called Character but I want to be able to create an array that has the name of each attribute as well as integer values assigned to each of them. I was trying to use nested arrays to do this but I'm having problems creating an array that is mixed with integers and strings. In trying to change a label to an element in the array, it gives me exceptions saying I can't convert between a 1 dimensional array of Strings into a String.

Ideas?

Comment: By Basic you mean VB.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Visual Basic .NET and simple need to create String/Integer pair, then Generic Dictionary is the structure you need:

```
Dim aList As New Generic.Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

aList.Add("Attribute1", 123)
aList.Add("Attribute2", 456)
aList.Add("Attribute3", 789)

Dim iValue As Integer = aList("Attribute2") '456
```

It's strongly typed and values are easily accessible by their keys.

***UPDATE*** Below is the more universal approach that can accept variable number of values of different types for each given key. Also it's implemented in a class like you needed.

First define a class like this:

```
Public Class MyClass1

  Private m_aMyList As Generic.Dictionary(Of String, ArrayList)

  Public Property MyList As Generic.Dictionary(Of String, ArrayList)
      Get
          Return m_aMyList
      End Get
      Set(ByVal value As Generic.Dictionary(Of String, ArrayList))
          m_aMyList = value
      End Set
  End Property

  Public Sub InitList()
      m_aMyList = New Generic.Dictionary(Of String, ArrayList)
  End Sub

  Public Sub AddValuesToList(i_sKey As String, ParamArray i_aValues() As Object)
      Dim arrList As New ArrayList

      For Each o As Object In i_aValues
          arrList.Add(o)
      Next

      m_aMyList.Add(i_sKey, arrList)
  End Sub

  Public Function GetListByKey(i_sKey As String) As ArrayList
      Return m_aMyList(i_sKey)
  End Function

End Class
```

It defines a public property that holds the list and 3 methods - to initalize the list, to add values to the list, and to retrieve the values.

When the class is defined like this, you can use it so:

```
Dim myObj As New MyClass1

myObj.InitList()

myObj.AddValuesToList("Attribute1", 1, "a", 2, 3, "bbb")
myObj.AddValuesToList("Attribute2", "eee", 34, 23, "aqaa")
myObj.AddValuesToList("Attribute3", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "qqq")


For Each o In myObj.GetListByKey("Attribute2")

    If TypeOf (o) Is Integer Then
        'perform action on integer values
    ElseIf TypeOf (o) Is String Then
        'perform action on string values
    End If

Next
```

In this example you instantiate a class, initialize the list, add 3 items to the list with  variable mixed values and then retentive second item from the list and loop thru its values.

Comment: Are those able to have multiple strings and integers as an entry? I need a string, string, integer, integer, integer entry per key.

Comment: Will this sequence "string, string, integer, integer, integer" be the same for all the keys or some keys could have different sequences, e.g "integer, string, integer, integer...etc." and of variable number of elements?

Comment: It could be the same, but is it possible to have it not be? Also I did mess with dictionaries with this but I'm trying to make this as a property of a class. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes both cases are possible, but depending on which one you need - a slightly different approach is taken. And yes, you can have a class with a member of Dictionary type

Comment: I've updated my answer with a code example for universal approach

Comment: Thanks so much. I've only taken a year of computer science so I can entirely understand what you did but it would've taken me ages to arrive there haha.

Comment: Been there :) Please mark the response as answered if the solution was useful for u